# Expo Video component fails to recognize the resizeMode prop

Tags: react-native, video, expo

When using the expo Video component, it does not seem to adhere to the resizeMode property.
I am using =>
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
     31.0.0.tar.gz"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update expo-cli, because the libraries are damaged, create a new proyect with the new libraries and move the screens of the old proyect to the new proyect

Comment: You need expo: "32.0.0"